# How to setup routing so that it's redirected to Login if not authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to build a dashboard view for my application, I'm using redux to manage authentication.
So if the user is not authenticated i want them to be redirected to log-in, else to home.

I have a CustomLayout and a home component, login component, signup component.

Routing is handled first from app.js the to routes.js

here is my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import BaseRouter from "./routes";
import * as actions from "./store/actions/auth";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import CustomLayout from "./containers/Layout";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onTryAutoSignup();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
          <BaseRouter />
        </CustomLayout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

And this is my `routes.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Hoc from "./hoc/hoc";

import Login from "./containers/Login";
import Signup from "./containers/Signup";
import HomepageLayout from "./containers/Home";

const BaseRouter = () => (
  <Hoc>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomepageLayout} />
  </Hoc>
);

export default BaseRouter;
```

Also sharing `Layout.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Menu
} from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../store/actions/auth";

class CustomLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { authenticated } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu fixed="top" inverted>
          <Container>
            <Link to="/">
              <Menu.Item header>Home</Menu.Item>
            </Link>
            {authenticated ? (
              <Menu.Item header onClick={() => this.props.logout()}>
                Logout
              </Menu.Item>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Link to="/login">
                  <Menu.Item header>Login</Menu.Item>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/signup">
                  <Menu.Item header>Signup</Menu.Item>
                </Link>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </Container>
        </Menu>

        {this.props.children}


      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authenticated: state.auth.token !== null
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(logout())
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(CustomLayout)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom route component that checks to see if the user is logged and redirect to login if they are not:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) =>{
   return(
     <Route {...rest}
       render = {()=>isAuthenticated ? <Component /> : (
         <Redirect to = '/login' />)
       }
     />
   )
 }
```

and then use that instead of the Route component

Comment: Can you pelase give a little more info on how to add this, I'm a little confused after seeing a lot of tutorials on doing this.

Comment: Sure, which part confuses you?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, created a new file with this logic and imported it to routes, i had to import redux methods to get auth state in the new file.